# Error when trying to add records to database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, record

I have created a system included a database using mySQL on visual studio express 2010. One of the tables I have included in my tables is booking. When i tried to input records into this tabl from the 'show table data' option i get the following error:

"The data in row 1 was not committed
Error source: .net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: String or Binary Data would be truncated
The statement had been terminated

Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the changes"

I have tried inputting ('NewSequentialID') to the default value or binding property of the primary key, but the error still appears, and appears for every other table I have included in the database.

SOMEONE PLEASE HELP. I AM AT MY WHITS END.

Comment: include your database schema and the insert statement, or at least the values that you try to insert. it seems you try to insert a value that is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the data you want to import is not too long for each field you try to import. That is what the error message is about. For example, a field could be 40 characters, but you try to put 44 into it.